# Why is lambda running dynamodb scan multiple times?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

So I've got a dynamodb table `table1` with 2 items in it, dead simple.  I write some code to scan it, works great.  Until I put `console.log` into the dynamodb callback.  If you test the below code in a lambda with inline nodejs you get wacky results

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'go', secretAccessKey: 'away', region: 'us-east-1'})
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB()
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  var ret = await ddb.scan({TableName:"table1"}, 
    function(err, data){
        console.log("pulling " + data.Items.length)
        return data
    }).promise()
  console.log("done pulling")
  return new Promise((r,e)=>r(ret.Items.length));
};
```

Run 1: `INFO    pulling 2
INFO    done pulling
INFO    pulling 2`

Run 2: `INFO    pulling 2
INFO    done pulling`

Run 3: `INFO    pulling 2
INFO    pulling 2
INFO    done pulling
INFO    pulling 2`

It's not breaking the code, but it is freaking me out.  If I put actual code into that callback instead of just returning the result, I'd get all kind of problems.

Comment: You should check the `err` in the callback. Also, unrelated to the question but it is bad to set `accessKey` in the lambda, use IAM roles.

Comment: Why are you using scan and not query? scan is the most expensive way of getting data from DynamoDB.

Comment: In addition to what iTech said about using IAM roles, make sure to NOT to use the full access role. Make your own that has a policy for only the DynamoDB API calls you need.

Comment: It is pretty odd that you're using both the Promise API _and_ a callback function...

Comment: Do not use both the promisified SDK call and a callback. Just use the former.

Comment: What if I have to query for items by more than two paramters? As far as I know, query doesn't support that.